# how to create relationships many to many from array of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, relationships

I get a couple of user objects in @users. and i have a task object in params[:task]
Now i want to save the taskobject and add relationships between all @users and that task....

```
@users = User.find(session[:user_id], params[:user_task])
@task = @users.tasks.create(params[:task])
@task.owner_id = session[:user_id]      

if @task.save
  redirect_to task_path(@task)
```

all i get is an error like: undefined method `tasks' for Array.
How do i do it?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do here. How are you getting the users? What is in `params[:user_task]`?

Comment: im getting them from user_ids. first from the logged in user from the session and also from params[:user_task], which should be some user ids from checkboxes.

Comment: 1. I want to create the new task params[:task]
2. And add relationships to that task with all users in @users

Comment: Can you post your model associations code? i.e. `has_many`, `belongs_to` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first initialize the new task, assign its owner and save it, and if that is successful then you can create associations with all users.

Like this:

```
@task = Task.new(params[:task])
@task.owner_id = session[:user_id]
if @task.save
  @users = User.find(session[:user_id], params[:user_task])
  @users.each { |user| user.tasks << @task }
```

Comment: Its PERFECT now :)! Thank you